# How to switch fonts dynamically in react?

Tags: reactjs, fonts

I want to build a feature that lets the user choose which font is being used throughout the react app. The backend should tell the frontend which font to use. Assuming the user gives the system the font files he wants to be used in the app, how would it be applied?

The flow would be something like this -

1. User uploads font files in the settings page
2. Backend saves the font files the user wants to be rendered
3. Frontend takes the font files (from the backend) and applies them to the app.

My question is - how would the frontend apply this font globally? I'm thinking I would have to use styled components. Is there a way to do it without styled-components?

Comment: Have you tried dynamically editing your index.html file using something like 

`const style = document.createElement('style');  style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(  body {  font-family: YOUR-FONT  }  )  );  document.head.appendChild(style);`